# How to write fuctions that takes IntoIter more generally

Tags: syntax, rust, type-bounds

I was reading an answer to stackoverflow question and tried to modify the function `history` to take `IntoIter` where item can be anything that can be transformed into reference and has some traits `Debug` in this case.

If I will remove `V: ?Sized` from the function definition rust compiler would complain that it doesn't know the size of `str` at compile time.

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

pub fn history<I: IntoIterator, V: ?Sized>(i: I) where I::Item: AsRef<V>, V: Debug {
    for s in i {
        println!("{:?}", s.as_ref());
    }
}

fn main() {
    history::<_, str>(&["st", "t", "u"]);
}
```

I don't understand why compiler shows error in the first place and not sure why the program is working properly if I kind of cheat with `V: ?Sized`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I kind of cheat with `V: ?Sized`

It isn't cheating. All generic arguments are assumed to be `Sized` by default. This default is there because it's the most common case - without it, nearly every type parameter would have to be annotated with `: Sized`.

In your case, `V` is only ever accessed by reference, so it doesn't need to be `Sized`. Relaxing the `Sized` constraint makes your function as general as possible, allowing it to be used with the most possible types.

The type `str` is unsized, so this is not just about generalisation, you actually need to relax the default `Sized` constraint to be able to use your function with `str`.